# Pairing in Cryptography

Tags: pairings

I am having problems in doing pairing in cryptography. I have tried the PBC library but seems like it doesn't work and I do not understand the documentation because it uses C++ language.

Is there a library for pairing in cryptography using PHP language?

or is there anyone who can explain how pairing works in cryptography with an input and output?
For example: Weil Pairing or Tate Pairing which uses Miller Algorithm.

Thank You

Comment: In my opinion, learning C (the actual language of the PBC library) is worth the moderate effort. The _coding_  of number-theoretical cryptographic algorithms in PHP is unusual. That language seems more suitable to _use_ such algorithms that are externally implemented in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

As @fgrieu said [[here]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54046/pairing-in-cryptography#comment119591_54046), cryptography is usually not implemented in PHP. The best you can hope for is a binding/wrapper:

[Search "php crypto binding" on Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=php+crypto+binding)

Unfortunately because pairings are not widely used in practice it is unlikely that you find them in major bindings, and although there are many bindings/wrappers listed on PBC website I don't see any for PHP.

Again agreeing with @fgrieu, this can be the opportunity to learn C++. Libraries like PBC (but also the [RELIC toolkit](https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic)) provide a rather "high-level" abstraction of pairings so you can use pairings with a few simple lines of C++.

Did you follow the [PBC manual](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/)? It really takes you by the hand, if you need a basic use of pairings this should really suffice.

The RELIC toolkit does not have such a "beginner-friendly" tutorial but it is maintained (unlike PBC) and I find it nicer overall. To learn how to use RELIC you will have to read the test suite:

https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic/blob/master/test/test_pp.c

If you decide to learn the use of PBC or RELIC (or [MIRACL](https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL/)) and have questions about their use I think (community, correct me?) you might want to post question stackoverflow instead.